# Getting "Passed unnecessary parameters" Error When Creating RivalEntity with Zenject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

I'm encountering a "Passed unnecessary parameters" error while creating a RivalEntity using Zenject in my project, and I haven't been able to resolve this issue. Here are the details regarding the problem:

My factory class is as follows:

```
public class RivalFactory : PlaceholderFactory<RivalAIData, RivalEntity>
{
    public override RivalEntity Create(RivalAIData rivalAIData)
    {
        var entity = base.Create(rivalAIData);
        entity.SetAIData(rivalAIData);
        entity.Initialize();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The installer I'm using for setup is:

```
Container.BindFactory<RivalAIData, RivalEntity, CompetitorManager.RivalFactory>().FromComponentInNewPrefab(rivalEntity);
```

And I'm trying to create a RivalEntity with the following code:

```
_rivalEntity = _rivalFactory.Create(rivalAIData);
```

However, I'm getting a "Passed unnecessary parameters when injecting into type 'RivalEntity'.
Extra Parameters: RivalAIData" error in this case, and I haven't been able to figure out the cause of the error. I'm looking forward to your assistance. Thank you.

I attempted to create a RivalEntity using Zenject's factory method with the provided RivalAIData. I expected the creation process to succeed without any errors and for the RivalEntity to be properly initialized with the given data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `PlaceholderFactory` properly. If you look at the base class you will see that you SHOULD NOT OVERRIDE this method

```cs
public class PlaceholderFactory<TParam1, TValue>
        : PlaceholderFactoryBase<TValue>, IFactory<TParam1, TValue>
    {
        // Note: Most of the time you should not override this method and should instead
        // use BindFactory<>.FromIFactory if you want to do some custom logic
```

Instead of that you have 2 options:

1. For `MonoBehaviour` derived class you can mark some nested initialization method with `[Inject]` attribute inside `RivalEntity`. For standard class (that is not inherited from `MonoBehaviour`) you may define its constructor with parameter.
   You can find an example in the documentation, on the [factory page](https://github.com/Mathijs-Bakker/Extenject/blob/master/Documentation/Factories.md#custom-factories).

```cs
public class Enemy
{
    readonly Player _player;
    readonly float _speed;

    public Enemy(float speed, Player player)
    {
        _player = player;
        _speed = speed;
    }

    public class Factory : PlaceholderFactory<float, Enemy>
    {
    }
}

public class EnemySpawner : ITickable
{
    readonly Enemy.Factory _enemyFactory;

    public EnemySpawner(Enemy.Factory enemyFactory)
    {
        _enemyFactory = enemyFactory;
    }

    public void Tick()
    {
        if (ShouldSpawnNewEnemy())
        {
            var newSpeed = Random.Range(MIN_ENEMY_SPEED, MAX_ENEMY_SPEED);
            var enemy = _enemyFactory.Create(newSpeed);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

2. if you have thought very carefully and decided that you just need to use override Create. Then you should set `RivalFactory` inherited from `IFactory<RivalAIData, RivalEntity>`. In this case you have to care about container injection by yourself. As an example:

```cs
public class CustomFactory<TParam, TObject> : IFactory<TParam, TObject>
  where TObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly DiContainer _container;
    private readonly Transform _parent;
    private readonly TObject _prefab;
    public CustomFactory(DiContainer container, Transform parentTransform, TObject prefab)
    {
        _container = container;
        _parent = parentTransform;
        this._prefab = prefab;
    }
    public virtual TObject Create(TParam option)
    {
        TObject monoObject = _container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<TObject>(_prefab, _parent);
        /*Do something with the object*/
        return monoObject;
    }
```

P.S As I can see, there are architectural design issues in your code. Because the initalization called from the constructor and the parameter that has to be part of initialization is passed to method that is made only for setting the parameter, that hints that something is wrong. I can't be sure for 100%. But I strongly recomend you to think about how to  use option 1. You can pass the `RivalAIData` as a paramter in `[Inject]` method. And call initialization from some kind of controller.

And if you have only 1 prefab that is the same for every `.Create` call. Then you must not pass it as a parameter at all. You have to bind it inside container. And create some `[Inject]` method that accepts it as a parameter.

Whatever you choose, I highly recomend you to read the factory.md page from the beggining till the end.